# Obtain all the points of the orbit of a celestial body in the solar system

Tags: spice

How can I render (or plot) the orbit of a planet using SPICE? Sorry, I'm not English and I don't know how to say to draw the path that the planet follows around the Sun (their orbit or, maybe, trajectory).

I want to do something like this:
[image]

I only need to get the data for the orbit, and then I have the method to drawing it.

And I think I can use [oscelt](https://naif.jpl.nasa.gov/pub/naif/toolkit_docs/C/cspice/oscelt_c.html) and [conics](https://naif.jpl.nasa.gov/pub/naif/toolkit_docs/C/cspice/conics_c.html).

Comment: Why do you think `oscelt` is relevant? That gives you the [osculating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osculating_orbit) elements from the state (position & velocity) vectors. But if you know the state vectors (for a sufficient number of points) you can plot the orbit in 3D.